# restore page status, knockout site tutorial section

Tags: knockout.js

This is about how knockout site restore page status. Every time I go to this page http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro, I type in something then click the run button, and go to another site, then click the back button so that the browser go back to this tutorial page. This page will prompt a window saying "You've been on Introduction before. Continue where you left off?". Does anyone how they implement that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: learn.knockoutjs.com appears to be using Local Storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#localstorage